# What ViewModelStoreOwner to use for ViewModelProvider in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I've creating a test activity that updates some text in my MyViewModel.

I'd like to observe these changes in a **Fragment**, but when I use

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

it gives me a different instance of MyViewModel than that used in the activity, which results in my `onChanged()` callback in the fragment not being called.

Only when I modify that same fragment code to

```
HomeViewModel homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);
```

does the fragment get the same instance of MyViewModel as the activity - so `onChanged()` is successfully called.

However, I'm not sure if using `getActivity()` as the ViewModelStoreOwner is the proper way of doing things as I haven't seen this in any examples anywhere. I'm wondering if there might be a better ViewModelStoreOwner I should be using in this instance?

Answer (score 6):

> I'm wondering if there might be a better ViewModelStoreOwner I should
>   be using in this instance?

You should use `activity` instance for sharing the same instance among fragments in the same activity.

Both Activity and [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment) implements their own [ViewModelStoreOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStoreOwner) interface and implements the `getViewModelStore()` method. `getViewModelStore()` provide the `ViewModelStore` instance which is used to store the `viewmodel` objects, created by the `ViewModelProvider`.

Note: [ComponentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity) implements the `ViewModelStoreOwner` interface and `FragmentActivity` (parent of AppCompatActivity) inherits the implementation.

So both Activity and Fragment have specific implementation for the `ViewModelStoreOwner` interface methods and store the viewmodel instance as per the  `lifecycle` of the objects(including the configuration changes).

Since fragments belong to activity get the same activity instance so using the `getActivity()` will result in using the `ViewModelStoreOwner` object of the activity. To share the objects among fragments, simply use the activity instance for creating `ViewModelProvider` which will use the same `ViewModelStoreOwner` in all fragments hence will return the persisted object of `viewmodel` (if created before).

Comment: Can `Application` be ViewModelStoreOwner?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I verified the Application API and it's not possible.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you can use AndroidViewModel which has access to Application if it is needed somehow, but not as ViewModelStoreOwner.

Answer (score 1):

Having an `Activity` which does as little as possible has become a "best practice" for some time now, so the scenario of an `Activity` and a `Fragment` which need access to the same `ViewModel` instance may not be covered by many guides.

But "there is no rule without an exception", and your scenario is similar to the one where an `Activity` has two `Fragment`s which need to share data.

In this case, one uses the `Activity` scope for the `ViewModel` to make sure every component will have access to the same instance. See also the section ["Share data between fragments"](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) in the View Model Overview at [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)